# Three textviews (side by side) below one textview(centrally positioned)- Android

Tags: android, textview, programmatically-created

This is my first question so pardon any convention I might have unknowingly overlooked.

Now, I want to create a long table in which each element has centrally positioned textview and below it, three textviews side-by-side. I have tried TableLayout, which makes the cells aligned (and I dont want that). I have tried LinearLayout which makes it appear either vertical or horizontal, not the kind of mixture of both that I need. I tried RelativeLayout which happens to be too cumbersome and I still couldn't get my result. Most probably, am making a conceptual mistake somewhere. All this is to be done programmatically. Can somebody help?

Comment: please draw rough image and post,  it will help us to give an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about putting a TextView and a Horizontal LinearLayout containing three TextViews in a Vertical LinearLayout or a RelativeLayout?

```
<RelativeLayout>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txt"></TextView>
    <LinearLayout 
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_below="@id/txt" >
        <TextView></TextView>
        <TextView></TextView>
        <TextView></TextView>       
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

**OR**

```
<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <TextView></TextView>
    <LinearLayout 
        android:orientation="horizontal">
        <TextView></TextView>
        <TextView></TextView>
        <TextView></TextView>       
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Hope this helps.

P.S: I haven't added id, width, height, text etc. :) Just a structure.

Comment: Thanks a ton. Solved in 5 minutes. So any kind of views can be nested in any manner? Always? Am 1-week old in android so didn't know about nested views.

Comment: Yes, @braincrash you can nest them and create any layout you want to :) good luck..